# Love2d shader - get positions of all mesh vertices in pixel shader

Tags: glsl, shader, love2d

Please, i got a shader which properly draws texture on mesh-quad with proper interpolation.
Problem is, i currently have to send data of all 4 mesh points separately used in pixel shader as "extern" data to get the right positions of pixels.

I need to have all 4 positions available for pixel shader to get the proper positions, but id like to get them from data i am sending in the love.graphics.draw() so i dont have to double-send. both to improve performance and make code cleaner. (mesh contains no z coordinates so proper interpolation is derived from 4th coordinate).

Transformations sent during love.graphics.draw( mesh, ... ) are available to me in TransformMatrix and already being applied, but i still dont have access to the mesh vertices sent during love.graphics.draw() so i supply it beforehand as "extern".

Is it possible to access all mesh vertices in pixel shader without having to supply the array in additional function?

*math in pixel shader is derived from screen_coords, and no mesh positions or transformations apply on it directly

Mesh data:

```
v = {
    { 0,0, 0,0, 255,0,255,255 };
    { 150,0, 1,0, 0,255,255,255 };
    { 100,200, 1,1, 255,255,0,255 };
    { 0,200, 0,1, 255,255,255,255 };
};
mesh = love.graphics.newMesh( v, "fan" )
mesh:setTexture( image )
```

Draw mesh:

```
love.draw()
    shader.on() --shader on
    shader.sendVertices( v[1],v[2],v[3],v[4] )
    love.graphics.draw( mesh, 250, 250, 0, 2, 3) --mesh to draw
    shader.off() --shader off
end
```

Function to supply pixel shader with vertices:

```
function sendVertices(v1,v2,v3,v4)
     gl_send(glsl,"vv",v2,v3,v4,v1,v1)
end
```

Shader:

```
glsl=love.graphics.newShader[[
    extern vec2[4] vv;

    vec2 v1 = vv[0];
    vec2 v2 = vv[1];
    vec2 v3 = vv[2];
    vec2 v4 = vv[3];

    //vertex shader unmodified

    //pixel shader
    some really long math derived from screen_coords, using all 4 positions 
    v1 to v4, which are exactly same positions as vertices sent to vertex 
    shader before matrix transformation.
]]
```

Comment: This sounds very much like [an XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). What are you trying to do that you feel you need to do this?

Comment: more like why i need to do this, i am "trying to fix" shader someone made before me to work more properly, building up on existing math. if there really is a reason to do so, i am unsure.

Comment: i need to operate only with x,y coordinates, so more proper solution could be modifying vertex shader and then use proper coordinates in pixel shader, but it would still mean i need to access all vertices sent to mesh in vertex shader onstead of pixel shader, as long as i am not supplying x,y,z and camera position.

Comment: if you ask if its necessary to do so, it is not. this shader is more like a challenge for me as id like to figure out how love2d shaders operate to be able to construct proper shaders for it in future or give proper help to other people in this matter. simply trying to figure out how are data sent and used in TransformMatrix was a great deal for me, as none of that is posted on wiki or anywhere else and these questions were already asked by people who gave up instead.